# PhantomJs GhostDriver not allowing me to click on submit (Grant Access to Box) works with chromewebdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, box, ghostdriver

I am attempting to automate the process of Oauth 2.0 with selenium.
I managed to get the entire process to work ChromeWebdriver ( headless and non-headless mode).

I want to use the code with phantomJS, as well but I cannot get the last button to press the "Grant Access to Box".

I know the button is visible since this condition works:

```
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#consent_accept_button")));
```

I have tried various methods of clicking the button:
actions 
javascript executor
and element click/submit
None of these seem to cause it to go to the next page.

Grant access to Box
                                Granting access to Box...

I was expecting the url from the driver to be http://127.0.0.1/api/code?state=csrftoken&code=somerandomstring
but it returns the url for this page so I know it's not advancing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it had to do with the redirect string going to a local host address not resolving. Can't have it go to an address that gives a connection refused exception.  HtmlUnitDriver works better for this implementation.